# Arithmetic overflow from CType function for IntPtr long values

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am getting arithmetic overflow exception below. Why is `CType` not handling long values (from `IntPtr` variable) where it should accept any object? What is the work around here?

> Exception: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Note: I am using .Net 2.0 in VS2013

**CODE**

```
    Dim testValue As Long
    testValue = 919016853520  'It can be 0 also sometimes.

    Dim lHkey2 As IntPtr
    'lHkey2 = testValue
    lHkey2 = IntPtr.op_Explicit(testValue)

    If (CType(lHkey2, Boolean)) Then
        Console.WriteLine("A")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("B")
    End If
```

Comment: It is simply because it doesn't fit.  You are running 32-bit code, the maximum value for IntPtr is 2147483648.   VB.NET never avoids reminding you that 919016853520 is a pig that don't fit that poke.  You definitely need to explain in which way 919016853520 is a sane Boolean value.

Comment: to add to what @HansPassant said ; the problem here isn't `CType` but the assignment either using op_Explicit or with the IntPtr ctor ; on a 32bits system it will always produce an Overflow exception you can see in the [reference documentation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/intptr.cs,d99bf6ad49979009) (in C#) for 32 bits there is always a cast to int somewhere before storing the internal value and that is this operation which raise the exception

Comment: @HansPassant I am running the application in 64 bit configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be related to defining an IntPtr(64 bits) on a 32-bit operating system.

See:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/837ksy6h(v=vs.110).aspx